# How to derive the rate of flow of flux?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, gauss-law, flow

This derivation is from Mechanics by DS Mathur, but I cannot understand this derivation from the first chapter, please help me.

How is the velocity component along X axis  $v_x-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial v_x}{\partial x}\delta x$ defined here?

i know it is a part of some expansion series but i still cant figure it out how this equation was defined

[image: rate of flow of flux: Application of divergence and curl]

Answer (score 1):

The series the writer has in mind is a *Taylor series*. You should look up *Taylor series* in a textbook, but the writer is using the series in such a truncated form that, for the purposes of this derivation, you can think of it simply as a linear approximation. It works like this...

The velocity component $v_x$ changes almost linearly with $x$ over the very small region of the parallelepiped. So we treat $\frac {\partial v_x}{\partial x}$ as constant. Clearly for an x-wise displacement $-\frac 12 \delta x$ from P, the change in $v_x$ is $$\delta v_x = \frac {\partial v_x}{\partial x}\times \left[-\frac 12 \delta x \right].$$
You should be able to take things from there.